# Riddle of J Krishnamurti

Tags: enlightenment, awareness

What was the philosophy(if we can use that word) of J Krishnamurti. He sounds very abstract nor did he gave any examples just string of complex words with implicit meaning. Can you explain me his philosophy?

Answer (score 1):

Krishnamurti was not a philosopher of the western type. He was an Indian mystic ( not in the traditional look and feel ) who uses a western taste language to make us think and contemplate about the important things of life.
Many of his writings and YouTube videos can be easily found on the Internet.

Comment: Sure sir, but how a student of philosophy understands what krishnamurti offered.